# Transfer the focus in to right hand side among the JTextFields in java swing

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a small application. I used transferFocus for transferring focus to another text field. But this is my problem; my cursor was always left hand side, even the field which contains the value. Why is it happening? Can you help me to fix this problem?

Comment: Works fine for me. The text field remembers the last position of the caret. So if the caret was at the end of the field when you lost focus it will return there. If the caret was at the start of the field it will return there. If this is not your behaviour then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: problem happens only after setting values in text field using settext.i setted 5 texts in 5 fields.when i locate cursor in to right hand side of the field by using right navigation button then it works.by default it goes to the left hand side.but if we once manually navigates to right hand side then it is fine.is that possible to locate cursor position in to right hand side.if i entered values in field manually then navigation works pefectly.